# html select menu options running off page

Tags: html, css

As described by the title, I have an issue where the character length of my select menu options is forcing the select menu hover to run off the right side of the page. Is there a fix for this. Just a standard select element.

```
<div style="position:absolute;right:30px">
 <select id="mySelectMenu" name="my select menu" style="width:150px">
    <option value="">&gt; Select Ship to Location</option>
    <option>This is an extremely long option that forces the select menu option out of the screen margin.</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

jsFiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/gchristman/GtyrQ/

I'd like to state the web page is a two column design and the select menu appears in the right column. This becomes an issue when your using a single monitor and your browser window has been maximized. The options that have character length's that exceed the given width of the select menu's remaining screen space disappear outside of the browser window. Is there a way to alter the select menus hover position to never exceed the right edge of the page?

Comment: Can you please post some code, or a link to the site, or put it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Without being able to see HOW your page works, no one will be able to suggest help.

Comment: Even worse people people may take 'stabs' in their dark, basically wasting their time and yours with incorrect solutions.

Comment: @Diodeus I think I described the issue pretty well.

Comment: George, there are a zillion ways to set up a page like that. Specifics are important.

Comment: @Mark I added sample to JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using absolute positioning you'll need to set your `right` position to allow for the width of your menu: `150px`

Comment: I only used absolute position to show the example. I'm actually using bootstrap and placing the select menu in a right column. It becomes an issue when the browser window forces the screen width to narrow.

Comment: Unfortunately it's government and I need to be very cautious in what I post. I just want to know if there is a way to provide position to the hover options similar to how it's done with a nav bar with hover menus. I can't have the options extending past the browser window. Positioning the select menu to the right side of the page will achieve the same test results.

Comment: Then, as Mark suggested above, go to JSFiddle and re-create the problem in a base case example.  You don't need to reproduce your code, just real code that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I think this is a windows / browser problem.  I noticed it happens in IE and Firefox, but not Chrome.

I think the only solution is to not set the width of the select (remove style="width:150px"), then it fits.  However, I realise that's probably not the best solution.